# How can I use the stored username and password in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have multiple db connections setup in Oracle SQL Developer. Every username and password is stored with the "save Password" option in the Database connection.

I have a script that queries multiple db's.

```
SELECT * FROM table_on_DB1;

conn username/password@server:1521:DB2
SELECT * FROM table_on_DB2
```

Running this from the worksheet of DB1 works fine. But the pain is that the username and password are now in the script. I assume there is a way to use the stored username and password from SQL Developer. How can I use the stored username and password from Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: "I assume there is a way to use the stored username and password from SQL Developer." What are you basing that assumption on?

Comment: You might want to look at the command-line version, SQLcl, and invoke that repeatedly from a shell/batch script instead, once for each connection - perhaps using a wallet to handle the credentials.